# VBA Excel How to maintain filters when copying a row

Tags: vba, excel, filter

So I got a row with associated Filters on them (there's an arrow on each of these cells and when you click on them, the filter box appears which allows the user to filter specific content). But I'm having a slight issue, this is the code I use for copying one row from one sheet to another:

```
Sheets(Name).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _
     Sheets("Monthly").Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(Sheets("Monthly").UsedRange.rows.Count - 1)
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

The problem is, when this code copies the row, they lose their filter properties. Is there a way to keep this information?

Comment: you should apply filter in `Monthly` sheet explicitly

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand, my vba knowledge is very basic @simoco

Comment: if I understood you correctly, you copy entire row from first sheet (where autofilter is applied) to second sheet (`Monthly`) and you want autofilter be copied as well. In that case you sould apply autofilter in second sheet explicitly, i.e. if you copy data in row 10, then use sth like this to apply filter on that row: `Sheets("Monthly").Range("A10:Z10").AutoFilter`

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That's exactly what I was lookiing for @simoco :| How do I accept your answer in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments:

Autofilter should be appied explicitly on sheet `Monthly`.
Say, if you copy row №1 from sheet1 (with autofilter) to sheet `Monthly` in, say, row №10, then you should use this line to apply autofilter:

```
Sheets("Monthly").Range("A10:Z10").AutoFilter
```

change row number and columns to suit.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Range.AutoFilter method will apply to the entire row, so you can just put the first cell of the row like this...

```
Worksheets("Monthly").Range("A10").AutoFilter
```

Also, for more control, you can pass additional arguments:

```
Worksheets("Monthly").Range("A10").AutoFilter _
    field:=1, _
    Criteria1:="nameToMatch", _
    VisibleDropDown:=True
```

In Excel VBE (Visual Basic Editor), just highlight anything you want to find more information about and hit F1 to bring up help.

The Excel Developer Reference can be very helpful.